# How to remove the decimal and take only the whole number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, decimal

i have output = "70.00" i want only to get "70" through SQL server

Comment: And what do you want for 70.67?

Comment: declare @i decimal(5,2)=70.00
select cast(@i as int)

Comment: You are using quotes, is 70.00 a decimal or a string?

Comment: you have to decide whether you want to `round` the decimal number to integer OR you just want to `truncate` the decimal part of the decimal?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
SELECT FLOOR(70.00)
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(70.00 AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

use ROUND () ([See examples](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1589/sql-server-rounding-functions--round-ceiling-and-floor/) ) function in sql server

> select cast(round(70.0,0) as int)